# How to use form input to update code?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a page where I need to filter certain values provided by an embedded widget  based on user input in a text field.
I can do this by appending certain parameters to the widget code embedded on the page and refresh the page

How do I take the user input , replace the widget code and refresh the page?

this is the code I might need to append to the widget code that already exist on my page.
%22filter%22:%7B%22keyword%22:%22userprovidedvalue%22%7D,

I am using jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to handle it by putting an onchange on the input field, and sending it to a function that reads the value off of the input field.  Alternately, you can have the submit button call a function, that first reads the value off the input field, then performs whatever logic you need, then submits the form.

Jquery is often useful for making things like this easier and more intuitive, though it does have a bit of a learning curve to ramp up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can set the value in a variable. How do I pass that back to the jsp?

Comment: Generally, by having javascript/jquery manually set value fields in input tags, often using .value or .val() respectively.  That'll get sent back up to the JSP just like the values in any other form input field (assuming that the input field is inside the form).  Frequently, this is what `input type="hidden"` tags are used for